# Push JSON File to Firebase

Tags: json, firebase

I've got a large JSON file that I'd like to push to my Firebase. It's currently in a specific format that I'd like to slightly change when pushed.

My current JSON file looks a bit like this:

```
"item": [
    {
      "title": "Hernia Repair",
      "dc:creator": "realph",
      "content:encoded": "A hernia occurs when an internal part of the body pushes through a weakness in the muscle or surrounding tissue wall. Your muscles are usually strong and tight enough to keep your intestines and organs in place, but a hernia can develop if there are any weak spots.",
    },
    ...
]
```

While my Firebase items look like this:

```
"services" : {
    "-JfTLQsxlZr6W2JWwMMd" : {
      "description" : "Hernia repair refers to a surgical operation for the correction of a hernia (a bulging of internal organs or tissues through the wall that contains itself.",
      "title" : "Hernia Repair",
    },
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to push each one of these `item`s to the `services` object that's already set up in my Firebase. But I'd like to push each item to a new unique id (i.e. -JfTLQsxlZr6W2JWwMMd), just like it is in my Firebase object (above). I also want push the `title` to `title` and push `content:encoded` to `description`.

Is this even possible? Doing this would potentially save me a lot of time going forward.

Any help from someone that is familiar with this sort of thing would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Update**

This is what I was thinking to do, but I don't believe it's wired up correctly. I'm getting back a unique key with the `console.log`, but no item is being added to the `services` object:

```
$scope.convertItems = function() {

  for(var i=0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {

    var newService = {
      title: title,
      description: 'content:encoded'
    };
  }

  var promise = ServiceService.add(newService);

  promise.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data.name());
  });
};
```

Comment: this sounds like a fairly basic data migration: load the existing JSON, loop over the items and push them into your Firebase. Which of these steps is giving you problems? Can you show what you've already done?

Comment: Haha, I thought of doing it this way, but I thought it sounded too simple. I'll finish writing how I thought to do it and post the results...

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Updated my original question with the function I'm trying. No luck at the moment though, I seem to be doing something wrong.

Comment: That all seems Angular and AngularFire stuff, which is not what you initially seemed to be asking about. Why don't you simply do this standalone, without Angular? `items.forEach(function(item) { ref.push({ title: item.title }); });` seems simple enough and saves you from struggling with Angular.

Comment: I think I managed to solve this last night with this solution: `snapshot.forEach(function(snap) { var newService = { title: snap.child('title').val() }; var promise = ServiceService.add(newService); });`

Comment: Wonderful. Feel free to self-answer and accept.

Comment: Wondeful. Feel free to self-answer and accept.